# How can I coax Eclipse into displaying missing @Nullable/@NonNull "Annotate" commands?

Tags: eclipse

According to https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M6/#annotate-command I should have `Annotate as @Nullable` and `Annotate as @NonNull` as options when right clicking the types in a method signature.

The following things I have already done:

- I have locations for external annotations configured
- I have annotation-based null checking enabled under Compiler/Errors/Warnings as per the link
- I have performed Maven/Update, Project/Clean and restarted Eclipse
- I have checked the .log file and found no errors or relevant warnings

But those options still do not show up for me. I am using the latest release of Eclipse (2020-12, 4.18) and I have also installed https://github.com/lastnpe/eclipse-external-annotations-m2e-plugin.

Anything else I need to do ?

Comment: The location for the external annotations must be a folder inside the workspace to make these commands work. Do you have that?

Comment: I did not have the folder inside the workspace (it didn't say anything about needing that, and the project source code was in an external drive) but after your comment I removed the project and cloned it fresh into the workspace. No change, still no options like that when I right click the return type.

Comment: The [instructions can be found in the help here](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_external_null_annotations.htm#create). The external annotation location (where the `.eea` files are stored) must be a folder (not a ZIP) inside the workspace (e.g. for the system library you have set the external annotation location to [this folder](https://github.com/lastnpe/eclipse-null-eea-augments/tree/master/libraries/java)). If this does not help, please show what you have with screenshots. I can confirm that it works for me.

Comment: It appears that the location not only has to be inside the workspace, but actually use the 'In Workspace' setting (which I am not sure lastnpe can set on its own). Even specifying an external location that actually is inside the workspace will not work if its given as a relative or absolute path. Thanks for helping me track this down, if you want to post an answer I'll happily accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the help/documentation the pre-requisites are named, which must be fulfilled, in order to be able to create external null annotations:

- [Java development user guide > Using external null annotations > Creating external annotations](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_external_null_annotations.htm#create)

An often overlooked pre-requisit is that the **external annotation location** must be **inside the workspace**:

[image]

Even if you would use the *External Folder...* button in this dialog and choose a folder that is inside the workspace, it would not work. Therefore use the *Browse...* button in the first option here.

Comment: "Even if you would use the External Folder... button in this dialog and choose a folder that is inside the workspace, it would not work" - that was my problem, thank you!